# How to access android google account on web application

Tags: android, mobile, web-applications

We have a web application, a e-commerce, which we are looking for ways to facilitate user authentication.
We don't have an app and our solution is totally responsive.
For authentication, we've already developed integration with Facebook and Google.

Our question is to perform web authentication in an integrated way with android, looking, for example, the Google account of the user registered on the phone.

In app, you can search for local accounts for authentication, but I don't know if there is any library or functionality, which allows us to make this request integrated, through an application running on the browser.

Tks.

Comment: You need to provide a more wide idea and explanation about what you are asking. This question is too generic and with no details

Comment: Hey, Carlos, I improved the specification. Did it make the problem more readable? Tks.